# JOIN 2 Tables and SELECT more cell

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Hi I have problem with mysql. I have 2 table.

table work and table person.

In table work I have 4 column with ID person Like

```
person1, person2, person3, person4, person5
  5          3       111      15       8
```

It must be that.

Now I want to select any row with table work but with name person.
Firstly I used this:

```
JOIN person p1 ON(w.person1 = p1.id)
JOIN person p2 ON(w.person1 = p1.id)
JOIN person p3 ON(w.person1 = p1.id)
JOIN person p4 ON(w.person1 = p1.id)
JOIN person p5 ON(w.person1 = p1.id)
```

AND USED select LIKE

```
SELECT p1.name, p2.name, p3.name....
```

BUT IF I have many rows LIKE 10000 this query will to slowly.

How change it to use 1 JOIN?

Answer (score 3):

Your `person` table is not normalized so in order to retrieve data you will have to join multiple times like you found or you can use a `UNION ALL` query to *unpivot* the data.

This type of query will be similar to this:

```
select *
from work w
inner join
(
  select person1 p_name
  from person
  union all
  select person2
  from person
  union all
  select person3
  from person
  union all
  select person4
  from person
  union all
  select person5
  from person
) p
  on w.person1 = p.p_name
```

By unpivoting the data you are taking your columns and converting it to rows so you can perform one join on the data.

Comment: Fine but when I have 1000 rows in my table I should using select 1000x5 soo my table will slow

Comment: @user2011304 ... which is why normalization is important and not just busy work that "they" make us do.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make all that in one JOIN, your option could be review the DB design, because 1000 join is not normal...

My best Advice would be create a relation table, so you will have something like

I.E:

**table_person 1 is friend of table_person_2**

you wont need 1000 join to know who is friend of who... you just need a join, with the right table structure and index.

Please take a look to [E/R Modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)

**EDIT**

My Advise is do not have one table with 5 columns (person1,person2,person3...), create a extra table with person1 and person2, and add there all the relations between them.

right now you have

```
person1, person2, person3, person4, person5
  5          3       111      15       8
```

I would recommend to have this in a table.

```
person1, person2
  5          3  
  5         111  
 5          15  
 5           8
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the data in the two columns?  I'm not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: You don't understand me. I have to show table Like this :  | cellX | CellY | CellZ | person1 (not id name) | person2 (not id name) .... Before I used 3 table First Work olny with cellX, CellY, CellZ, secend In name person and id work. Last in relations with id_person and id_work. But how to display table like | cellX | CellY | CellZ | person1 (not id name) | person2 (not id name)